# Sklearn: Pass class names to make_scorer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to setup a custom scorer in sklearn (using make_scorer) to use during cross-validation. Specifically, I want to calculate Top2-accuracy for a multi-class classification example.

Here, technically, my problem is that I need to evaluate the probabilities (using *needs_proba=True*) and need the list of classes in order to make sense of the probability matrix.

I have compiled an example below. While I can setup the custom scoring function for a non-cv example by providing the classes in the *make_scorer* call, I am not able to set this up properly for the cv-case, where the classes will be determined dynamically and thus I need to read them in only during the evaluation.

I know that there are many similar questions, but I did not see a working solution for my specific use case, thus I would be great if somebody could help me (Excuse my ignorance in case this is solved somewhere).

Thanks a lot in advance!
David

*PS: If I am not mistaken, for all use cases of make_scorer that involve the probabilities, actually the class labels should be crucial, thus I assume that this is a generic problem.*

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

data = load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target

# DIRECT USE OF CUSTOM SCORER ##################################################################################
# Simple test train split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

# Define the model and fit it
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X = X_train, y = y_train)

# Function that returns either the prediction with the highest likelihood or the correct prediction, 
# if it is within Top n by probability 
def top_n_consolidation(y_label, y_prob, class_names, n=2):
    top_recs = class_names[[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(y_prob), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)][0:n]]
    if any([i == y_label for i in top_recs]):
        return y_label
    else:
        return top_recs[0]

# Calculate accuracy based on Top n predictions
# --> NOTE: THIS FUNCTION RELIES ON class_names IN ORDER TO MAKE USE OF THE PROBABILITIES
def accuracy_top_n_function(y_labels, y_probs, class_names, n=2):
    cons_preds = [top_n_consolidation(y_labels[i], y_probs[i,:], class_names, n) for i in range(y_probs.shape[0])]
    return accuracy_score(y_true=y_labels, y_pred=cons_preds)

# Make a custom scorer for Top 2 classifications
accuracy_2 = make_scorer(accuracy_top_n_function, class_names = model.classes_, n=2, needs_proba = True)
# --> NOTE: THIS WORKS, BECAUSE model.fit WAS ALREADY EXECUTED

# Calculate Top 2 accuracies
accuracy_2(clf=model, X=X_test, y=y_test)

# USE OF CUSTOM SCORER FOR CROSS-VALIDATION ####################################################################

# Define a new model to ensure that we distinguish from the case above
model_cv = LogisticRegression()

# Define custom scorer for the cv case
accuracy_2_cv = make_scorer(accuracy_top_n_function, class_names = model_cv.classes_, n=2, needs_proba = True)
# NOTE: THIS IS NOT WORKING AS model_cv.classes_ IS NOT YET KNOWN!

# Define custom scores to use
custom_scoring = {'acc'       : 'accuracy',
                  'acc2'      : accuracy_2_cv}

cross_validate(model_cv, X, y, cv=3, scoring = custom_scoring, return_train_score=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [custom scoring method described here in user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) where the signature is:

```
func(estimator, X, y)
```

Here `estimator` is a fitted estimator with train data from the cross-validation split, so `estimator.classes_` will work.

```
def accuracy_2_cv(estimator, X, y_labels):
    n=2
    y_probs = estimator.predict_proba(X)
    class_names = estimator.classes_
    cons_preds = [top_n_consolidation(y_labels[i], y_probs[i,:], class_names, n) for i in range(y_probs.shape[0])]
    return accuracy_score(y_true=y_labels, y_pred=cons_preds)
```

Now pass this directly to `custom_scoring` without wrapping in `make_scorer`:

```
custom_scoring = {'acc'       : 'accuracy',
                  'acc2'      : accuracy_2_cv}
```

Comment: Dear Vivek, thanks for your quick and very helpful reply -- that works like a charm! Thanks a lot!